# Laravel Rename Project

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Hello guys I'm using laravel 5.2. Now I need to rename the lararvel project or move everything that is in it to another folder. What will I need to change to get my project working.

I want to know one more thing that if I want to make a project in a directory without it's root folder in other words I need all the subfolders not the root what will I have to do for that because I tried running this command but from the looks of the error it looks like it needs a name `laravel new .`

Comment: This is too broad as it is.  It sounds liek you want to move the contents of a directory into another place or simply rename the parent directory.  This is nothing to do with Laravel.  As for the question regarding `laravel new` that is ignored now days in favor of using composer directly.

Comment: @ash, actually (if he's asking about moving directory), he will also need to set up his web server (and maybe restart it) to make his app work. If he'll just move directory, his app will not work.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin that is not the question - renaming a file and a webserver? What? That makes no sense.

Comment: @ash, well not everybody know such things (like set new settings in web server and restart). Be more tolerated to newbies. He could spend hours finding out why his app stopped working after renaming project directory.

Comment: This is not a forum, this is a Q&A - if the question is not clear enough or does not conform to Stack Overflows rules then it should be closed.  I voted this being too broad and that the OP should clarify what they are asking before we can help.  You have jumped to a conclusion you don't even know what the question is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to change anything.

Comment: Actually, he'll need to change web server settings.

Comment: yeah  you are right I do not need to change anything. Thanks